# Incomplete file error while trying to install Matlab

Tags: installation, matlab

I'm attempting to install MATLAB R2013a on my PC. I know it's compatible because I have a 64-bit architecture. When I try to open the file after having downloaded MATLAB from my university's website I receive the following message:

```
Archive:  /home/chihiro/Downloads/R2013a-Linux-64.zip.crdownload
[/home/chihiro/Downloads/R2013a-Linux-64.zip.crdownload]
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
zipinfo:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of /home/chihiro/Downloads/R2013a-Linux-64.zip.crdownload or
          /home/chihiro/Downloads/R2013a-Linux-64.zip.crdownload.zip, and cannot find /home/chihiro/Downloads/R2013a-Linux-64.zip.crdownload.ZIP, period.
```

I'm not sure what this means, but any hints would be appreciated since I just switched to Linux and I'm not used to how it operates yet.

Answer (score 2):

A `.crdownload` file extension indicates a file which has been ***partially*** downloaded by Google Chrome (or Chromium). This is typically because your computer shut down or Google Chrome was terminated halfway through the download. Such a file will be unable to be opened by a file archiver or another program.

You should try to redownload the file then try again.